# Can a counting sort be considered in-place when the problem constrains the number of input values?

Tags: sorting, counting, in-place

I was doing this problem on leetcode:

> Given an array nums with n objects colored red, white, or blue, sort
> them **in-place** so that objects of the same color are adjacent, with the
> colors in the order red, white, and blue.
>
> Here, we will use the integers 0, 1, and 2 to represent the color red,
> white, and blue respectively.

While there is a fairly satisfying solution where you shove the 0s to the left and the 2s to the right with a single-pass, it's hard for me to understand why a counting sort wouldn't also count as an in-place solution to this problem.

After all, you only need constant space for the computation.

You could argue "Sure, but if I say there's N colors, it's no longer constant space", but that's simply a different problem, and the intended solution doesn't work for N colors.

So what makes the counting sort not an excellent, valid answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you may have three integer variables to count occurrences of each color, and then fill the initial array with the right number of each color, in the right order. This has a constant space cost (in addition to the input array), and is a perfectly valid answer to the question.

Sure too, if the number of colors is not constant anymore, then this method does not hold, but then you cannot make in-place counting sort; you will have to turn to another algorithm to sort in-place, at the price of a higher time complexity.